# Access specific table from MySQL database with Python

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a MySQL database named `my_database` , and it that database there are a lot of tables. I want to connect MySQL with Python and to work with specific table named `my_table` from that database.

This is the code that I have for now:

```
import json
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(user = "root", password = "", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "", database = "my_database")
cursor = connection.cursor()

print(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_database.my_table"))
```

This code returns number of rows, but I want to get all columns and rows (all values from that table).
I have also tried `SELECT * FROM my_table` but result is the same.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what 'number of rows' mean? What that number is, and what is the total number of records in that table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the [documentation](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html)? You need to fetch the results after executing: fetchone(), fetchall() or something like this:

```
import json
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(user = "root", password = "", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "", database = "my_database")
with connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_database.my_table")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

You probably also want a `DictCursor` as the results are then parsed as dict.